# Two variable in one one variable

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, query-builder

I have two queries.

```php
$createdServer = Server::where('created_at', '>=', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subMonth())
    ->selectRaw('COUNT(id) as createserver, DATE(created_at) as date,DAY(created_at) as day')
    ->groupBy('day', 'date')
    ->orderBy('date', 'ASC')
    ->orderBy('day', 'ASC')
    ->get();

$deletedServer = Server::where('deleted_at', '>=', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subMonth())
    ->selectRaw('COUNT(id) as deleteserver, DATE(deleted_at) as date,DAY(deleted_at) as day')
    ->groupBy('day', 'date')
    ->orderBy('date', 'ASC')
    ->orderBy('day', 'ASC')
    ->onlyTrashed()
    ->get();
```

The output is:

```
 "deletedServer": [
  {
   "deleteserver": 1,
   "date": "2019-04-29",
   "day": 29
  }
 ],
 "createdServer": [
  {
   "createserver": 2,
   "date": "2019-04-29",
   "day": 29
  }
 ],
```

My requirement is:

```
 "allServer": [
  {
   "deleteserver": 1,
   "createserver": 2,
   "date": "2019-04-29",
   "day": 29
  }
 ],
```

**deleteServer** and **createServer** count data in database.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve with below code:

```
$allSevers = collect([
            "deleteserver" => $deleteServer->count(), // retrieving the deleteServer count
            "createserver" => $createServer->count(), // retrieving the createServer count
            "date" => date('Y-m-d'), //date format in Year - Month - Date
            "day" => date('j') // date format for mday
        ]);
```

Comment: You wanted all last month createserver and delete server data?

Comment: Could you clarify what you need? Where the answer went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`merge` function would solve the issue in your current case: [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-merge)

```
$merged = $createdServer->merge($deletedServer);

$merged->all();
```

*Edit:*

```
$merged = $createdServer[0]->merge($deletedServer[0]);

$merged->all();
```

Comment: output is:     "allServer": [
    {
      "deleteserver": 3,
      "month": "2019-04"
    }
  ],   this not propely work...

Comment: @SmitPipaliya I have updated the answer. Please check it.

Comment: Error is: Call to undefined method App\Server::merge()